# [React Hooks]Cannot get changed state in onClick arrow function with params

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

To show my question here is a Demo code.(I'm using React Hooks and Antd.)
**My Question is:**
when `currId` state is changed and I click `MyButton` the state is still `''` (which is the initial state). onClick event is an arrow function and in it is `showModal` with params, if there's no params `currId` can be seen changed but now with params state isn't changed. May I ask what is the reason of it and how I can get changed `currId` in `showModal`?

(**operation: click 'Change CurrId' button --> setCurrId('12345') ---> click 'MyButton' ---> console.log(currId)**)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Button} from 'antd';
const MyComponent= () => {
      const [currId, setCurrId] = useState('');
     const changeCurrId= async () => {
        setCurrSolutionId('12345');      
  }
      const showModal = async (num:any) => {
        console.log("☆ currid：");// I cannot get the currId state '12345' but ''
        console.log(currId);
        console.log("☆ num：");//I can get the num params 5
        console.log(num);
      };
    return (
          <>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={changeCurrId}>Change CurrId</Button>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={() => {showModal(5)}}>MyButton</Button>
          </>
      );
    }
```

Comment: How did you change the `currId`? You didn't call `setCurrId` to update the value of `currId`.

Comment: I changed my currId when click another button which isn't showed.
（ in its onclick event I changed state with setCurrId(“12345”)）

Comment: `const MyComponent= () => {
      const [currId, setCurrId] = useState('');
      const showModal = async () => {
        console.log("☆ currid：");
        console.log(currId);
      };
    return (
                <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>MyButton</Button>
      );
    }`

code like above can console log the changed currId but with params(showModal(5)) cannot...

Comment: Can you also include the code where you were changing the state?

Comment: `const MyComponent= () => {
      const [currId, setCurrId] = useState('');
     const changeCurrId= async () => {
        setCurrSolutionId('12345');      
  }
      const showModal = async (num:any) => {
        console.log("☆ currid：");
        console.log(currId);
      };
    return (
                <Button type="primary" onClick={changeCurrId}>Change CurrId</Button>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={() => {showModal(5)}}>MyButton</Button>
      );
    }`
The whole structure is like this.

Comment: I first click the `Change CurrId` button and then click `MyButton`

Comment: Please edit your question with the relevant [mcve], do not post code in the comments.

Comment: have changed my demo code about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const MyComponent= () => {
      const [currId, setCurrId] = useState('');
       const changeCurrId= () => {
        setCurrId('12345');      
       }
      const showModal = (num:string) => {
        
        console.log("☆ currid：");
        console.log(num);
      
      };
       const changeCurrentIdAndShowModal = (id : string) => {
         setCurrId(id); 
         showModal(id)
        console.log("☆ id：");
        console.log(id);
      
      };
    return (
            <>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={() => changeCurrId()}>MyButton</Button>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={() => showModal('5')}>MyButton</Button>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={() => changeCurrentIdAndShowModal('12345')}>MyButton</Button>
            </>
      );

    }
```

Is this the intention you want?

Comment: num is  params I need to use not related to currId state.

Comment: I have changed my demo code. You can have a look about it.

Comment: @Cody I saw the updated comment and corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is what I want to do.First setCurrId and then get the changed currId in showModal.

Comment: I changed simply it, but I don't know what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have commented my demo code. I can get the params num which is not a question.The question is that I cannot get the currId state which is set '12345' after I clicked the button'Change CurrId' and then 'MyButton'

Comment: I need to do the opration (click 'Change CurrId' button --> setCurrId('12345') ---> click 'MyButton' ---> console.log(currId)).

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-driscoll-59e4p?file=/src/App.tsx) With reference to the sandbox link, the process you describe works as it is.